Impossible to stop a route with inflight messages (which are in redelivery) when using camel-spring-rabbitmq
Hello Camel users and developers.
We have an issue with Apache Camel in combination with the camel spring rabbitmq component. Previously we used the now deprecated camel rabbitmq component. (I have a simple example project on github, see below)
The problem:
If a message in the route is in redelivery, then this route cannot be stopped properly when using camel spring rabbitmq component:

The consumer is stopped
The route is terminated
But the in-flight message (in redelivery) continues to be executed (Thread remains sleeping/running)

This is not the case with camel rabbitmq component: The redelivery is interrupted (java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted), and the message is back in the RabbitMQ ready for the next delivery (when the route is restarted).
Example project:

github: https://github.com/Skrrytch/camel-and-rabbitmq-issue
This demonstrates both components so you can see the different behaviour
see readme.md for details like code description, how to run and reproduce

It would be kind if someone can help here because we need a way to interrupt a redelivery by stopping the route(s) for maintenance as well as stop, remove the message from queue and restart.
Note: First we have tried this with Camel3/SpringBoot2 (see example project) and upgraded now to Camel4/SpringBoot3 ... with the same results, but without an available camel rabbitmq component.
With kind regards
Bert.
By the way: I previously posted this issue as a new user by accident.
